# Tailwind classes use slash character, but slash character isn't allowed in class names

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS uses classes like [`w-1/2`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) that contain the slash `/` character. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/2064544), slashes aren't allowed inside of class names. Why does it still work? What spec are the browser vendors actually implementing?

Comment: This answer is quite old and if you read a little bit further people say that slash is totally valid symbol. Some in depth article for example https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes, quite recent csswg discussion https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7129#issuecomment-1069331981

Comment: You're muddling HTML and CSS. A class name, even if it's a tailwind class name, is HTML, not CSS, and HTML attribute value rules apply. There, a `/` is a normal character. On the other hand, in a CSS selector the `/` must be escaped, but tailwind is hiding that detail behind its abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tailwind classes in class names. Only omit the  `\`  slash and use `left-1/4` instead of `.left-1\ /4`. The answer you are referring is very old